# Zooming mapbox to the bounding box

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapbox, route-me

I have an instance of `RMMapView` having a route path annotation. I need to get a `snapShot`of the overall route because I need to use that `UIImage` elsewhere. Here's the code I have:

```
RMSphericalTrapezium trapezium = [self.mapView latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox];
[self.mapView zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest:trapezium.southWest northEast:trapezium.northEast animated:NO];  
UIImage* image = [self.mapView takeSnapshot];
```

However, the image has only the end point annotation and is not zoomed appropriately to include the complete route (+ start annotation and end annotation).

What's wrong with this code? How can I set the zoom levels correctly?

I use the `mapbox-ios-sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

Zooming in this way just moves to the *map's* bounding box but doesn't take into account any annotations (though, it sounds strange that the entire map would not contain your annotations — I'd have to see an image to understand better).

What you probably want is to iterate all of your annotations and create a bounding box that contains all of them. This code inside of `RMAnnotation.m` may help you if you reuse it elsewhere as you iterate the map's annotations:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/abe470a4764b586ca1dc915dd0da46eb0bdef7f9/MapView/Map/RMAnnotation.m#L210-L234